# Change dynamically created layer's minZoom after render

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I want to change the minzoom of dynamically created layer after the rendering.

I tried couple of things:

```
map.getLayer('my_custom_layer'); // this gets the layer

map.getLayer('my_custom_layer').minzoom = 5;
map.getLayer('my_custom_layer').setMinZoom(5);

map.setPaintProperty('my_custom_layer', 'minzoom', 5); // couldn't make this work at all.
```

Is it possible to change the layer's zoom programatically after it's created and rendered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [map.setLayerZoomRange](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#setlayerzoomrange):

```js
map.setLayerZoomRange('my-layer', minzoom, maxzoom);
```